# Economy ticket, but enjoy first-class service?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, luxury

Recently, I've been watching YouTube videos of people reviewing First/Business Class seats/suites. I noticed that on some of the airlines (mostly non-US) airlines, there is a "companion" seat within the First/Business Class seat/suite. This companion seat is usually across from the tray table and from the video reviews, is meant for guests to visit you.

Therefore, is it possible for 2 people to fly together and have **Person A** buy a First/Business class seat/suite, but have **Person B** buy an economy seat and then have **Person B** join **Person A** for meals and other First/Business class amenities?

Answer (score 6):

Generally no. Almost all airlines have a policy that passengers must stay in their ticketed cabin.

Whether temporary visits are allowed really depends on the airline staff. You can always ask nicely and see what happens. Here is an extreme example of where there was a real need for an economy passenger to "visit" business class to attend and elderly relative and where it worked fine on one leg of the flight but not on the other. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4409554/United-forced-arthritic-grandma-94-cramped-seat.html

Answer (score 4):

Not usually. Most airlines have a "visitor" policy stating that passengers in first can go visit friends in coach, but not the other way around. I've heard of cases where exceptions are made for children (hopefully teenagers) sitting in coach are allowed to visit their parents in first class, but that's a rare occurrence.

Remember that flight attendants have a list of who is supposed to sit where, so they know whose seat it actually is. Also, the food is loaded based on those who actually purchased first class (though there are some extras of course).

Most of all, airlines talk a lot about "maintaining" first class in the sense of keeping people out who aren't willing to pay for it. Even if there's not an explicit rule they would make one very quickly if they caught people doing it.

Answer (score 0):

NO, this is not permitted.  However....

There have been occasional reports and my personal experience, that **Business Class** passengers can visit **First Class** passengers (on 3 Class aircraft) with few if any issues.

Even more 'allowable' is First Class passengers visiting Business Class passengers.